# Query regarding the storage of .AVI files to FTP server or mysql server

Tags: matlab

I have to design an application where the user is choosing a video and entering a secret message which will be embedded in the video.The video will be split into audio and image frames and the message will get embedded in both the audio and image frames using PGP(Pretty Good Privacy).The audio and image frames will then be combined to form a modified video. Now I have to store this modified video in a server. Then later again I have to extract this modified video from the server. Please can anyone guide me through this? Or provide me better solutions to this problem. I would appreciate that.

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/internet-file-access.html + http://www.mathworks.com/help/database/index.html#database-connection

Comment: @Cheery Thanx a lot for the information. I also want to ask how will a video be stored in a database? In the form of Image frames and audio or it can be stored as .AVI file?

Comment: You can store it in blob column. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html But the best way is to keep it locally and store in db only path to the file.

Comment: @Cheery Ya I think saving the path to the file in a database will be better. Could you please tell me how to do that?